# Measurement unit of a tensor product combinations of quantum states in Pusey-Barrett-Rudolph (PBR) theorem proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, tensor-calculus, measurements, quantum-measurements

I'm dealing with the [Pusey-Barrett-Rudolph (PBR) theorem proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pusey%E2%80%93Barrett%E2%80%93Rudolph_theorem), in which we are using a basis built of linear combinations with tensor products.

I'm trying to figure out whether measuring those linear combinations is still in terms of spin unit? Because our states [kets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) with zeros and ones represent spins, but I'm not sure if linear combinations are changing our units?

If it is not the spin unit, then what is it? Maybe this measurement has only mathematical sense but not physical?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whether I've understood your question correctly: are you asking about the physical significance of the observable corresponding to the basis which you have described (to which physical quantity does it correspond to)?

Comment: Yes this is what I'm actually asking about :)